# How to install and build fomantic-ui in GitLab CI?

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, semantic-ui, electron-updater, fomantic-ui

Background: I'm trying to use electron-updater with my electronJS code on a [GitLab public repo](https://gitlab.com/cataxcab/the-wall)

I'm following this guide: https://gist.github.com/Slauta/5b2bcf9fa1f6f6a9443aa6b447bcae05

However, the GitLab CI build stage keeps failing with the error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
     at DestroyableTransform.errorHandler (/builds/cataxcab/the-wall/node_modules/fomantic-ui/tasks/config/tasks.js:108:29)
     at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:203:15)
     ...
     at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (/builds/cataxcab/the-wall/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:93:3)
     at /builds/cataxcab/the-wall/node_modules/gulp-clean-css/index.js:38:16
     ...
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! fomantic-ui@2.8.4 install: `gulp install`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the fomantic-ui@2.8.4 install script.
```

**Complete error**: https://gitlab.com/cataxcab/the-wall/-/jobs/550995808

**My latest .gitlab-ci.yml file**: https://gitlab.com/cataxcab/the-wall/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

This seems to be the same as this issue: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2971 ; However, I tried the workarounds there, it didn't work:

```
rm -rf node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer
npm install gulp-autoprefixer@2.3.1
```

Any help would be appreciated, including pointers if there are gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in the Pull request [#1469](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI/pull/1469) and will be merged in Fomantic v2.8.x